# Quicksort - difference in time

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I'm testing Quicksort based on Niklaus Wirth algorithm. I'm checking how much time I need to sort an array. There is interesting thing that for an array consisting elements in these sequence:

1    3    5    7    9    10    8    6    4    2 (example how an array looks like for bigger instance)

0.14 seconds - array with 99999 elements

5.91 seconds - array with 100000 elements

0.11 seconds - array with 100001 elements

It last quite long for 100000 elements. Do you have any idea why?

I'm using Windows.
Code with Quicksort in C++:

```
    void quicksort (int l,int p)
    {
        int i, j, x, w;
        i=l;
        j=p;
        x=tab[(l+p)/2];

    do
        {
            while (tab[i]<x) i=i+1;
            while (x<tab[j]) j=j-1;

            if (i<=j)
            {
                w=tab[i];
                tab[i]=tab[j];
                tab[j]=w;
                i=i+1;
                j=j-1;
            }

        }while(!(i>j));

        if(l<j)quicksort(l,j);
        if(i<p)quicksort(i,p);
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to meet us halfway. You have not specified what language you used to implement Quicksort, or the type of computer/OS you're using. BTW: your implementation includes random partitioning at the beginning, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quicksort exhibits suboptimal time performance if it consistently selects a pivot that results in a uneven partition.

The usual speed $O(n \log n)$ in time depends of getting a division of the input into two equal (or at least nearly equal) parts at each pass. If you get a highly unbalanced division regularly then you get a very different time behavior. In the worst case---in which only one element is removed in each pass---quicksort ends up with a time behavior of $O(n^2)$. This is the case when you select either the first of the last element as the pivot and the input is sorted.

Your pivot selection---from the middle---requires a slightly more complicated input to get pathological behavior, but depending on the details of your input and on the exact length (because you pick the "middle" element) you can have one or more "bad" passes. It looks like you get a great many bad passes at that one length.

Choosing the pivot element randomly is generally considered sufficient to reduce the odds of pathological behavior to a satisfactory level.

Alternately there are other algorithms (like mergesort) whose division does not depend on picking a value from among the inputs which don't have the failure mode.

Comment: As I showed my input is like this:

1 3 5 7 9 10 8 6 4 2
Elements are growing to the middle of an array and then elements are lower and lower.

Comment: @luke - if you know that your elements are strictly ascending, then strictly descending, you would not want to use quicksort.  First, linear time algorithms exist for such a list.  Second, your strategy would pick a pathological first (and possibly future) pivots.

Comment: Pick a pivot which is the median of the first, middle, and last elements in the sub-array.  This makes most common pathological cases, (already sorted, reversed, and actually random) behave well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're seeing a large number of non-compulsory cache misses due to address conflicts, but it's hard to verify this without actually measuring the number of cache misses.  That said, 50x is a rather large performance difference.  This sort of large inconsistency should go away if you adjust your pivoting strategy (as J.M. suggests in the comments, you really should be using a random pivot).